# Count Unique Dates in Relation to Another Field

Tags: ms-access, unique

I have a member identifier reference number in one field and a date in another field.

The database contains rows where the member identifier appears more than once. For a given member, who can have multiple records (rows), sometimes the date is the same and sometimes it is different.

I want to count the number of unique instances of date against the member.

- If a member has three records and they all have the same date, I want the query to return the value 1.
- If a member has three records and two are 01/01/2005 and the third is 10/06/2003, I want the query to return the value 2.
- If a member has three records and three different dates I want the query to return the value 3.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
Select MemberID, Count(*) As DateCount
From (Select Distinct MemberID, DateField From YourTable)
Group By MemberID
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a `GROUP BY` clause with the aggregate function `COUNT`... but on a subquery that uses `SELECT DISTINCT` to get unique User ID/Date combinations first.

With this record set:

[image: Record set]

You can either use the Query Designer to make two queries, the first one being:

[image: query designer for "DistinctDates" query]

And the second, which uses the first query you created, being:

[image: query designer for "CountQuery" query]

To get the output you want:

[image: query results]

Alternatively, if you're like me and prefer to work with raw SQL, you can just use this SQL in a single query:

```sql
SELECT DistinctDates.UserID, Count(DistinctDates.TheDate) AS NumDates
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Table1.UserID, Table1.TheDate FROM Table1) AS DistinctDates
GROUP BY DistinctDates.UserID;
```

One thing extra that I'd like to note, which I learned just now off of [W3Schools's SQL SELECT DISTINCT Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_distinct.asp) page, is that most other RDBMS engines may allow you to use `DISTINCT` on fields in a query. However, The MSAccess/Jet Engine doesn't support that syntax. If you're in another DB engine at any point, you could just do this:

```sql
SELECT Table1.UserID, COUNT(DISTINCT Table1.TheDate) AS NumDates FROM Table1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, this gets me in the direction of what I want but not quite what I'm looking for - instead of there being more than one row for an ID I'm looking for just one row, and a count of the number of unique dates, so in the above example UserID "1" would have a count of 2, and UserID "2" and "3" would each have a count of 3.